# How to label atoms or groups "backwards" in ChemDraw

Tags: software, notation

I'm trying to draw L-tyrosine with the hydroxyl part of the phenol as `HO` instead of `OH` as it appears in the ChemDraw image. Everytime I type in `HO`, it automatically corrects to `OH`. I have the settings in `ACS Document 1996` style. Is there anyway to make the format render my "backwards" type?

[image: L-Tyrosine]

Comment: I have version 14.0.0.117 and it works as expected: "HO" instead of "OH". It should automatically rotate the labels.

Comment: I have 15.0.0.106 and I don't think it worked when I had version 14 either.

Comment: The problem with the question is, that it becomes a software issue, that might have a very specific solution. Support might be the best option there. However, as it is working with my version and you have a newer one, I suppose it should work with yours, too. You can find me in [chat] to talk about it. Have you ticked "File > Preferences > Building/Display > Automatic Atom Label Alignment"? Have you tried entering "OH" instead?

Comment: Okay, so apparently typing it in as "OH" works.

Comment: If you type "HO". Click on it. Go to Text>flush right and it will also fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ChemDraw is a piece of software that attempts to be as intelligent as possible. In many cases, that is truly helpful, in others it can be annoying.

When labelling an atom in text mode, ChemDraw will automagically assume a label from left to right (i.e. in standard North American/European writing direction) and interpret the label as such. If it finds that the atom has bonds to the right but none to the left, as tyrosine’s hydroxy group has in your example, it will group the label into ‘sensible’ fragments<sup>[1]</sup> and reverse them. This makes sense if you think of rotating a molecule: If you had drawn tyrosine rotated by $180^\circ$, you would have wanted to add `OH` on the rightmost atom, not `HO`. If you then manually rotate the entire molecule within ChemDraw, you will notice the `OH` flipping into an `HO` as soon as it graphically makes sense to do so.

Note that if you just hover over the atom in lasso mode or bond adding mode and then hit `o` (lowercase!) it will automatically add `OH` (or `HO`, depending on the orientation) at that position. Hitting `o` again will remove the additional hydrogen (this holds true for all chemical elements that are attached to single letters regardless whether the atom is attached to a lowercase letter (i.e. `o`) or an uppercase one (`B` for boron)).

---

[1]: Consider `OTBS`: ChemDraw automatically recognises `TBS` as an abbreviation for the $\ce{TBS}$ group so when reversing, it becomes `TBSO`. However ChemDraw does not standardly recognise the triethylsilyl group $\ce{TES}$, so when reversing `OTES` it arrives at `SETO`. The preferred way would be to add an abbreviation to ChemDraw.

Comment: Note that you can view the known nicknames using _File>List Nicknames._ You can define your own nicknames using _Structure>Define Nickname._ Also note that ChemDraw breaks atom labels (not nicknames) into tokens that consists of an uppercase letter followed by any numbers or lowercase letters. Therefore, $\ce{-OH}$ is flipped to $\ce{HO-{}}$, whereas $\ce{-Br}$ is not flipped to $\ce{rB-{}}$.

Comment: @ortho How write you are in assuming a righting error there … ;)